# Continue after throwing an exception

Tags: java, exception, mockito

I'm throwing an Exception in my unit test, but after it is thrown, I still want to be able to continue testing

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(myMock).myMethod();
myMock.myMethod();
System.out.println("Here"); // this is never called
// Do verify and asserts
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just catch the exception:

```
doThrow(new MyException()).when(myMock).myMethod();

try {
    myMock.myMethod();
    fail("MyException should have been thrown!");
} catch (MyException expected) {
    // Do something
}

System.out.println("Here"); 
// Verify the mock, assert, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was catching the AssertionError. Also had to remove the expected value in the @Test annotation.